# Transform list of ndarrays into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multidimensional-array

I have a list of ndarrays that I want to transform into a pd.dataframe. The list looks like this :

```
from numpy import array
l = [array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
            0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]),
     array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]),
     array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])
     ]
```

The length of the ndarrays is a multiple of 12 (12 months) in this case it's equal to 36. I want the final output to look like this :

| Year | Jan | Feb | March | April | May |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: can you explain how you want to aggregate? What represent the sublists and lists?

Comment: can you provide the full/exact expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### reshaping

Assuming `l` the input, you can use:

```
from calendar import month_abbr
df = (pd.DataFrame(np.vstack(l).reshape(-1, 12),
                   columns=month_abbr[1:])
     )
df.insert(0, 'year', np.tile(range(1, len(l[0])//12+1), len(l)))
print(df)
```

or:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack([np.tile(range(1, len(l[0])//12+1), len(l))[:,None],
                             np.vstack(l).reshape(-1, 12)]),
                  columns=['year']+month_abbr[1:])
```

output:

```
   year  Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec
0     1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
1     2    0    1    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
2     3    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
3     1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
4     2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
5     3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    0
6     1    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
7     2    1    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    1    0    0
8     3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
```

##### previous answer: aggregation

Assuming `l` the input list and that each list represents successive months to form 3 years, you can `vstack`, aggregate (here using `max`), and reshape before converting to DataFrame:

```
from calendar import month_abbr
df = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack(l).reshape(len(l), -1, 12).max(axis=0),
                  columns=month_abbr[1:])
```

output:

```
   Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec
0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
1    1    1    1    0    1    1    0    0    1    1    0    0
2    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1
```

As it is ambiguous how you want to aggregate, you can also use a different axis:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.vstack(l).reshape(len(l), -1, 12).max(axis=1),
             columns=month_abbr[1:])
```

output:

```
   Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec
0    0    1    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    1
1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    0
2    1    1    1    0    1    0    0    0    1    1    0    1
```

Comment: I want to clarify this, each list in the input list l contains n runs (years), if n=3 then the lenght of each list is 36.
If len(l)=x, the length of the final dataframe will be 3x and the row "year" will contain numbers from 1 to 3 and the first 12 elements of the list will be in year=1, the second 12 elements will be in year=2 etc..

Comment: That's what I imagined (this is my first approach), but then how do you get 1 for the third year/Jan where individual values were all 0?

Comment: I was just giving a random example it's my bad. Using the approach where (axis=1), the final dataframe's length would be equal to the length of the intial list which is not what i want to get.

Comment: double check your example, I think it returns what is requested, no?